# Pandas: How do I get the key (index) of the first and last row of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with a datetime index and one field "myfield"

I want to find out the first and last datetime of the dataframe.

I can access the first and last dataframe element like this:

```
df.iloc[0]
df.iloc[-1]
```

for `df.iloc[0]` I get the result:

> myfield         myfieldcontent
>
> Name: 2017-07-24 00:00:00, dtype: float

How can I access the datetime of the row?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use select `index` by `[0]` or `[-1]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'myfield':[1,4,5]}, index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3))
print (df)
            myfield
2015-01-01        1
2015-01-02        4
2015-01-03        5

print (df.iloc[-1])
myfield    5
Name: 2015-01-03 00:00:00, dtype: int64

print (df.index[0])
2015-01-01 00:00:00

print (df.index[-1])
2015-01-03 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using pandas 1.1.4 or higher, you can use "name" attribute.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'myfield': [1, 4, 5]}, index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3))
df = df.reset_index()
print("Index value: ", df.iloc[-1].name) #pandas-series
#Convert to python datetime
print("Index datetime: ", df.iloc[-1].name.to_pydatetime())
```

Answer (score 1):

[jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320760/257635) is perfect. Just to provide an alternative, if you insist on using `loc` then you should first `reset_index`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'myfield': [1, 4, 5]}, index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3))
df = df.reset_index()
print df['index'].iloc[0]
print df['index'].iloc[-1]
```

Comment: probably not if index is datetime though